# Warning: Using unique option prefix pass instead of password is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead

Tags: mysql

MySql 5.6.30 on command line when I will try connect or execute any command (like `mysql -u root -p` or `mysql --help` or `mysqldump`) I got this alert/warning.

> Warning: Using unique option prefix pass instead of password is
>   deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the
>   full name instead.

I'd never saw this warning message.

Anyone knows why this is happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your /etc/my.cnf has the following in the config:

```
pass=*********
```

Change it to:

```
password=*********
```

and your error message should go away.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work to me.

As you can see:

`[client]
user=root
password=*********`

And the message continues to be shown.

Comment: Shouldn't it be under [mysqld]?